# Are the languages Wookiees and droids speak rare?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

One thing I see people use against Rey understanding the Wookiees' and droids' language in *The Force Awakens* is that both languages are heavily implied to be rare in the original six movies, notably in the original trilogy. I am wondering whether the languages are *really* implied to be rare or not, at least within the original six movies themselves.

Comment: Do you mean rare as in not many people understand them?

Comment: Well, a billion wookiees speak Shyriiwook and a trillion droids speak Binary. Define "rare".

Comment: When was Droidspeak implied to be rarely understood in the OT or PT? Certainly in the EU plenty of people could understand their astromechs. Most of the *Ghost*'s crew in Star Wars: Rebels can understand Chopper. Luke could understand Artoo by Episode V. A lot of humans weren't able to *speak* the Wookiees' language very well but that was 'cause they didn't have the vocal range IIRC.

Comment: In The Last Jedi Luke was able to recognise that R2-D2 had a potty mouth (he tells R2-D2 to watch the language in a sacred place)

Comment: There are two (separate) questions here. Both are answerable.